# Проведение конкурса в telegram

Tags: telegram

Вот в чем чуть:

Планирую устроить, конкурс в своём канале telegram. Победитель получит premium подписку. Возможность участвовать будет только у тех, кто пригласил 5 человек на канал. Победитель закрытого конкурса выбереться случайно.

Собственно говоря, как можно осуществить такой конкурс, чтобы все участники канала могли это наблюдать.

Смотрел разных ботов, но там нет возможности участвовать только тем, кто пригласил людей.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как провести конкурс с розыгрышем в телеграмм, в котором смогут участвовать только те, кто пригласил определённое количество человек на канал?